# Return last day per month (and week) in dataset

Tags: excel

[image: Share Price Data]

I have a large amount of daily stock market closing data that I need to report on, however I only need the last day of the month from each data set.

Given the dates of each month will differ year to year depending on weekends and public holidays I can't just use =EOMONTH(A2,0)

How do I extract, just the last day of each month from a data set probably using the MAX functionality in some way. Then I can just do a Vlookup to get the data for that date,

`[![Share Price Sheet][1]][1]`

Comment: Does it really matter if the last day is a weekend or holiday?
-
Are you wanting a sum between two dates, not sure what vlookup is supposed to do

Comment: If there is a public holiday and/or weekends the last data field may be something like the 24th of the month, meaning I can't just use the last calendar day i.e.30th as there won't be anydata. 

Vlookup would just be to create a second table that is based on monthly end price, not daily end price.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your date column is sorted by small to large, `index()` and `match()` could solve this problem.

Try to use:

```
=INDEX(A:A,MATCH(EOMONTH(DATE(D2,E2,1),0),A:A,1))
```

which point is set third argument to 1 in `MATCH` function.

[image]

If you want to get close price, in G2 cell write:

```
=VLOOKUP(F2,A:B,2,FALSE)
```

Comment: So that works, but it will return the month end data as many times as there are fields, in which case there is a lot of duplicate data.

Comment: @Scottyp Set year and month in column D and column E, the function will return the last_trading_date. You get duplicate because your setting in column D and column E are duplicated.

Answer (score 0):

Since the last date is found on the dataset you have, you can just select distinct your year & month in a new sheet, create a helper column combining the 2 columns.

Create the same helper column in your original dataset, sort dates by newest to oldest. And you can vlookup the exact date. If you just want the day part of the date, extract the date from the Date itself with the day formula

[image: snapshot]

Comment: I don't understand what you mean sorry.

Comment: Sorry, should be remove duplicates. Let's assume your data set is in Columns A to E (A = Decade, B = Year, C = Month, D = Date, E = Close). Copy entire Columns B & C into columns G & H. Select columns G & H, and hit on Remove duplicates (Data > Data Tools > Remove duplicates). Insert a column before column A, and on Cell A2, input the formula =C2&D2. Drag this formula the the final populated row. Then select Range A to F, and sort the  column "Date", sort it Newest to Oldest. next in Cell J2, input the formula =H2&I2. Drag this to the final populated row of Column H. Then vlookup(J2,A:F,5,0)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this just by `Pivot Table`

- Select your data (I used a snipped only)

[image]

- Insert a `Pivot Table`
- Use `Year`, `Date` and `Close` as your Row labels
- Use `Date` also as a value field
- Set `Date` in your value field to show `Max`, format to actually show dates and rename if you want, e.g. "Last Day"
- Click any date under any month in the row labels > `Filter` > `Top-Ten` > Choose to filter top 1 under `Last Day` and confirm.
- Format your pivot table to your liking, maybe hiding subtotals.

My end result looks like:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried using a pivot initially, however the closing share price was returning the sum or average price for the month rather then the closing price on the last day. I'm not sure how to get around that.

Comment: @scottyp, have a look [here](https://exceljet.net/pivot-table/pivot-table-latest-values) to see how to set to Max

Comment: That will show the max closing share price for the month rather then the last date.

Comment: @scottyp, have a look at my screenshot. And follow the steps. If you really don't know how, share a sample file and I'll create the table

Answer (score 0):

You could use a combination of [EOMONTH](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/EOMONTH-function-7314FFA1-2BC9-4005-9D66-F49DB127D628) and [WORKDAY](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/WORKDAY-function-F764A5B7-05FC-4494-9486-60D494EFBF33).

*For example:*
The date you're looking at is 21st November 2019.
`=EOMONTH(DATEVALUE("21 Nov 2019"),0)+1` will return 1st December 2019.

30th November is a Saturday, and for some reason the 25th to 29th November are holidays.
`=WORKDAY(EOMONTH(DATEVALUE("21 Nov 2019"),0)+1,-1,{43798,43797,43796,43795,43794})` will return 22nd November as last working day of the month.

Using cell references (D3 = Date, A1:A5 are the holidays):

```
=WORKDAY(EOMONTH(D3,0)+1,-1,$A$1:$A$5)
```